# Understand equations of a conducting sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, classical-electrodynamics

Can somebody explain to me, when the following two equations (equations 2.48 and 2.50 [in this document](http://physics.usask.ca/~hirose/p812/notes/Ch2.pdf)) are applicable and what $\Phi_s$ and $\Phi$ actually are? The thing is, I want to find general equations that determine the field produced by conducting spherical sphere in an external field and was wondering whether these are the equations I am looking for.

$$\Phi (r,\theta,\phi)=\sum_{l,m}\left(\frac{a}{r} \right )^{l+1}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\oint\Phi_{s}(\theta',\phi')Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi')d\Omega',\,\,\,\,r>a$$

$$\Phi (r,\theta,\phi)=\sum_{l,m}\left(\frac{r}{a} \right )^{l}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\oint\Phi_{s}(\theta',\phi')Y^*_{lm}(\theta',\phi')d\Omega',\,\,\,\,r<a$$

Or is it rather this equation (equation (17.3) in [this document](http://www.physics.udel.edu/~jim/PHYS809_10F/Class_Notes/Class_17.pdf)), probably they are one and the same:

$$\Phi (\mathbf{x})=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_S \Phi(\mathbf{x}')(\hat n.\nabla')G_D(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}')dS'$$

Comment: These equations are application of the Green function of a spherical surface to find the potential everywhere, with Dirichlet boundary conditions; and $\phi_s$ is the boundary condition.(given potential on the surface). Equations 2.48 and 17.3 in the first and second references respectively, are exactly the same thing. Your problem doesn't need these at all, and all you need is an expansion of the potential in spherical coordinates for $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: I think it's better to discuss such specific problems on chat. Here, these type of questions are off-topic.

Comment: How can one open a chat?

Comment: what do you mean by expansion in spherical coordinates? do you know the equation i ask for?

Comment: Maybe, you could post as an answer your suggestion to determine the electric field by a noncharged spherical conductor in an external field

Comment: @Lipschitz At 100 rep you can create your own (probably temporary) chat room for a specific discussion. But as long as you have at least 20 rep you can jump into an existing room, our main one being [The h Bar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). It's not always populated, and it won't necessarily get you the answers you want (remember people use it to hang out, not just answer questions), but you can give it a try if this is deemed off-topic.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could make the question more self-contained, so one can understand it without clicking a link, and as a protection against future link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you have a metal sphere with a total charge of $Q$ in an external uniform field. ($Q$ can be zero; It's the general case). Assume the field's directions is $\hat z$.

[image]

Since we usually choose the center of the sphere as zero potential point, to make the problem simpler we can substitute the charged sphere with a grounded sphere and a charge $Q$ at the origin. Nothing changes.

Now we solve the problem for the grounded sphere without considering the charge at the center and then add the two potentials:
$$\text{boundary conditions: }\,\cases{V=0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ r=R \\ V \to -E_0 r \cos \theta \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\  r\gg R }$$
$$V(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\left(A_lr^l+B_lr^{-(l+1)}\right)\mathrm{P}_l(\cos \theta)  $$
Applying these boundary conditions we will have:
$$V(r,\theta)=-E_0\left( r-\frac{R^3}{r^2}\right)\cos \theta$$
Now we add the effect of the charge $Q$:
$$V_{total}(r,\theta)=-E_0\left( r-\frac{R^3}{r^2}\right)\cos \theta+ \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{Q}{r}$$

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. But if the charge is zero then based on your reasoning the potential of a grounded sphere would be the same as for a sphere that is not grounded!

Comment: @Lipschitz Yes. It is so, because our potential reference point is the center of the sphere, and if you don't have any charge inside the sphere, the potential of the sphere itself will be zero.

Comment: and how do you get the potential inside a sphere with zero charge. By the way, thank you, you are a great help

Comment: @Lipschitz You're welcome! If you don't have any charges *inside* the metal sphere, the potential inside it will be constant, as Gauss's law states. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you, that was completely what I meant, you are a great help. by the way, so your equations still hold, if we would assume that our sphere is swimming in liquid mercury( I just say mercury in order to use a conductive media too) assuming that the electric field in mercury would still be homogenous as you assumed in your vacuum solution?

Comment: If you also answer this question( that deals with the question what changes if we have a conductor instead of vacuum) I will award a 50 credits bounty to you since you have been such a great help. By the way, if something is different it would be great if you could refer to equations!!! Thank you again!

Comment: @Lipschitz It just needs a qualitative treatment. If you replace vacuum with mercury, electrically there will be no distinguishable difference between the conducting sphere and the outer medium, since both are conductors. Though static electric fields are always zero in (isolated) conductive media, if we assume you somehow produce this field (like what you would have in a resistor connected to a constant voltage source with a constant current), the current and the electric field will exist in the sphere as well as the  outer medium homogeneously, without any observable (electrical) difference.

Comment: I think in your answer, there is a sign wrong, since you know have $V(r,\theta)=-E_0r\cos(\theta)$ for r large enough!

Comment: @Lipschitz Yes, I forgot the minus sign in the second boundary condition (the answer remains the same). It assumes the direction of electric field to be $\vec E_0=E_0\ \hat z$. I added a picture of the situation to the answer. Thanks!